# Solution verification in this Probability exercise.

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability

> There is a box with four drawers. The contents are respectively $GGG, GGS, GSS$, and $SSS$. You pick a drawer at random and a coin at random. The coin is $G$. What is the probability that there is another $G$ coin in the drawer?

Let $$A:= \text{The first coin that i take from the drawer is } G. \\ B:= \text{The second coin that i take from the drawer is G} $$

So i need to find $P(B \mid A)$.
\begin{align} P(B \mid A) &= \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)} \\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{4}\cdot1\cdot1+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{4}\cdot1+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}} \\ 
 P(B \mid A) &= \frac{2}{3} \end{align}

So the probability that there is another gold coin in the drawer is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Am i right?, the book says that the answer is $\frac{5}{6}$

Comment: You want the probability that you have selected drawer $1$ or $2$ given that you have selected $1$, $2$ or $3$.

Comment: As for a trivial way of calculating this quickly., treat every coin as distinct, so the first drawer contains coins $G_1,G_2,G_3$ while the second drawer contains coins $G_4,G_5,S_1$, etc...  Now, recognize that all of the twelve coins were equally likely to have been drawn.  Given that we had drawn a $G$ it was equally likely to have been any of the six $G$ coins... all of which except for $G_6$ have another $G$ coin present in the drawer with them.  Thus, the desired probability is $\frac{5}{6}$.

Answer (score 3):

You calculated precisely what you said you’d calculate, with $B$ the event that the second coin that you take from the drawer is a $G$. But that wasn’t the question. The question was about the probability that there’s another $G$ coin in the drawer. Fortunately you only have to change one of the numbers in your calculation to fix the mistake.

Comment: I see. Now, if i change $B$ for $B:="\text{There is another $G$ in the drawer}"$, the probability of $ P(A \cap B)$ must be $\frac{1}{4} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: @sango: Almost. You dropped the wrong factor in the second term. The $\frac12$ was the wrong one from the non-existent second coin draw; the $\frac23$ was the right one from the first coin draw.